# Excel VBA: Workbooks.Open(absolute_path) freezes Excel, except under one condition

Tags: excel, vba, file, file-handling

Under this line of code, Workbooks.Open(previous_absolute_path) freezes Excel most of the time, giving no error message:

`Set current_workbook = Workbooks(get_file_name(current_absolute_path))`

The surounding code:

```
If IsWorkBookOpen((current_absolute_path)) = False Then
    If previous_absolute_path <> "" And previous_absolute_path <> current_absolute_path Then
        Workbooks(get_file_name(previous_absolute_path)).Close True 
    End If

    Set current_workbook = Workbooks.Open(current_absolute_path)
    previous_absolute_path = current_absolute_path
Else
    Set current_workbook = Workbooks(get_file_name(current_absolute_path)) 'Causes Fail!
End If
```

`current_absolute_path` is a valid file path that is absolute. It seems every time the code runs there are windows at least being opened. However, in the newly opened workbook, no lines of code are ever executed in its`workbook_open()` from what I can tell from putting a message box as the first line of code of`workbook_open()` and the message box never appears.

The code does work, if and only if I have the workbook running this macro open, and before I run that macro, I manually open the workbook at `current_absolute_path`. I close that file and run the macro and it works without any problems.

`current_absolute_path`, is a confirmed valid file path. The line of code can open other workbooks within the same folder. Excel allows all macros and "trusts" files from the internet at this point. The folder of the workbook being opened is not protected.. and I do not have the skills yet to know where the problem is. What must be done?

**EDIT**: It's not manually opening the workbook that causes the Excel macro to run successfully the next time, specifically its manually closing it.

Comment: there is no `Workbooks.Open(previous_absolute_path)` in the code you provided. Also the double parens in this line `IsWorkBookOpen((current_absolute_path))` looks suspect. And does the offending workbook have links (especially a lot of them) in the workbook that may be updating on open?

Comment: OK! I meant to say 'Set current_workbook = Workbooks.Open(current_absolute_path)' causes the fail, both times. Any time I said  'previous_absolute_path' I meant 'current_absolute_path', I edited my question. With that said, there is no purpose for the double parenthesis now, I don't know where they came from, but that function always works, even before the program crashes. The offending workbook has no links, but has macros opening modifying other workbooks.

Comment: So this code will open a workbook that has `Workbook_Open` event code that opens still other workbooks and runs code on them? Try commenting out the `Workbook_Open` code in that workbook and just adding a `Msgbox` in that event (like you did, but without any other code).

Comment: Having only a `msgbox` allowed the `workbook_open` to run every time. (I ran the original code again afterwards and neither `msgbox` nor `Stop` ever executed for debugging). The purpose of this workbook_open function is to assign values to public global variables of the offending workbook.

Comment: There are links to other cells btw

Comment: so now add back in the code into `Workbook_Open` line-by-line to see what causes it crash and then determine a solution .... like maybe find another way around using public global variables.

Comment: I learned that Excel successfully opening the workbook manually was dependent specifically whether the offending workbook was previously closed manually, the "red X", or programatically closed. Omitting lines caused success because they caused errors elsewhere which required me to manually close the offending workbook. It doesn't make a difference opening it manually or programatically.